# IOS Overriding Local Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I created a `Local Notification` that triggers 60 seconds when a certain button(`SetButton`) is clicked. My problem right now is if `SetButton` is pressed again, it does not override the first press, it displays 2 notifications and so on. How do I make sure that the second press of the button overrides the first press and there isn't a build up of notifications ?

```
- (IBAction)SetButtonPressed:(id)sender {
      UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
      localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
      localNotification.alertBody = @"HEY GET UP";
      localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
      localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

}
```

My `AppDelegate.m`

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
     if ([UIApplication instanceMethodForSelector: @selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
         [application registerUserNotificationSettings: [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
     }

     if (localNotification) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to cancel previous local notification if you don't want it to fire. Or simply cancel all local notifications if you don't want to hold a reference to previously set notifications. And be aware that [UILocalNotification] is deprecated...

Comment: @RokJarc Hi, thanks for the answer but how do I cancel previous previous notification. I am still learning objective c

Comment: In that case the easiest way would be calling `[[UIApplication sharedAplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` just before you register a new one. Try it as the first line in your `SetButtonPressed:` method.  This way you don't really have to hold a reference to previously scheduled notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use notifications for that specific action you could cancel all notifications at once using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only have one type of local notifications in your app.

In that case you could keep it simple. Whenever you want to schedule a new one - cancel the previous one.

```
- (IBAction)SetButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"HEY GET UP";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
}
```